# How to key in numeric digit as enter in MS SQL Server 2012 column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, numeric

**I need store exactly numeric data in database.**

Let say have to save 123.200 or 123.1 exactly into database.
But result will come up 123.20 or 123.10 in database if column type set to decimal with fixed 2 digit.

What I can do if I just want 123.200 or 132.1 shown on database/report?

No need system auto convert to any other decimal.

Comment: Store it as a character type instead of numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the value "as is" in the `varchar` type.
The problem with this approach is that database would allow to store any string there, even if it is not a number, say `10abc.xyz23`

If you need to know how to present the number to the user, you need to store this information somehow. Since, each number in the column may be formatted differently, you need to store this formatting information for each row.

I'd store it as `decimal` type with large enough scale and precision to cover all possible ranges of your data and in addition to that have extra column `DecimalPlaces`, which would contain the number of decimal places your reporting engine should use when displaying the value.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, after follow you description, zero will gone if enter 123.40. I need present 123.40 exactly to end user.

Comment: When user enters `123.40` in your application it should parse it and detect that user has entered 2 decimal places. Then your application should store this information (2 decimal places) in the database together with the numeric value of 123.4. When your application presents this value back to the user it should format it accordingly, knowing that originally user entered 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* do this, then as others have suggested, you'll need to use a character data type to store it. I'd also add a computed column that makes the numeric value readily available also:

```
create table T (
    Val varchar(39) not null,
    Val_numeric as CONVERT(decimal(38,10),Val) persisted
)
go
insert into T(Val) values
('123.200'),
('123.1')

select * from T
```

Results:

```
Val                                     Val_numeric
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
123.200                                 123.2000000000
123.1                                   123.1000000000
```

When you need the "user entered" value, you use `Val`. When you need the real value, you use `Val_Numeric`. This also has the advantage that (without a complex check constraint), you cannot enter any invalid values into the `Val` column. E.g.:

```
insert into T(Val) values ('1.2.3')
```

Produces the error:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 12
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```